# The proto nested structure cannot be bound to http

Tags: go

When the kratos proto file uses the http interface when the structure is nested, the parameter assignment cannot go to the structure

[This`s my proto file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A1I8.png)

[This`s my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8HaJ.png)

[This`s my debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtHvZ.png)

I want like this：

```
pb.ListUserRequest{
   Page: {
      Index: 1,
      Size: 10,
   },
}
```

There is no binding parameter
what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http can't decode inner_object by 'GET'

1. use 'POST'

```
    option (google.api.http) = {
      put: "/user/v1/list"
      body: "*"
    };
```

proto:

```
message ListUserRequest {
  Page page = 1;
}
```

2.not use inner_object
proto:

```
message ListUserRequest {
  int32 index = 1;
  int32 size = 2;
}
```

Comment: post can not be resolved ；still nil

Comment: not use inner_object can be solved but I need to write the same thing every time